# es posible restaurar ubuntu al punto de recién instalado?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, ubuntu

es posible restaurar ubuntu  al estado inicial? estaba intentado añadir java y netbeans (las versiones mas recientes) a las variables de entorno y ahora me funciona todo mal, no me funciona ningún comando de la terminal. no quiero tener que reinstalar ubuntu.
  Si pudieran ayudarme también a añadir java y netbeans a las variables de entorno se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Marcelo deberias ver en un sitio de soporte sobre ubuntud y no este que es para resolver problemas de codigo.

Comment: Prueba preguntando en askubuntu